# Cypress seems to have stalled

Tags: cypress

I'm new to cypress and love the way it is architected. However, I seem to have run into a problem early on for a very simple thing that I'm trying to do.

My workflow is:
1) Visit the site
2) Enter username and password
3) On the next screen, type a number and press submit,
4) On the next screen, select a value from a dropdown and press enter.
5) I get to the landing page of my website.

Cypress works totally fine till step 4). It seems to stall at step 5. The test runner suddenly stalls and without warning or error, shows 
"Whoops, there is no test to run."

From here, when I click the "View All Tests" button, it takes me to the runner tool. There I see the indication that something is still running in the background. I tried waiting for more than 10 minutes but nothing happens until I click on the "Stop" action.

How do I debug this? Can I see what is happening via any log etc?

There could even be something wrong with my website as well, but without any log information, I'm unable to proceed further. Any help is appreciated.

To provide more context, I don't think this is a timeout based issue as if that were the case, cypress did report to me about this and stopped. I then increased the timeout.

My spec file

```
describe('My first test', function() {
    it('Visits  home page', function() {
        cy.visit('https://mywebsite.com:5800', {timeout: 400000}, {pageLoadTimeout: 400000}, {defaultCommandTimeout: 400000})


        cy.get('#USERNAME').type('myusername')
        cy.get('#PASSWORD').type('mypassword')

        cy.get('#loginbutton').click()

        cy.get('#SOMELEMENT_WHERE_I_TYPE_A_UNIQUE_NUMBER').type('8056')
        cy.get('#loginbutton').click()

        cy.get('#loginbutton').click()

    })
})
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you run [`DEBUG=cypress:* cypress open`](https://on.cypress.io/debugging#Debug-the-Command-Line) from the terminal when initially opening Cypress, there will be more debug log information printed there while you run your tests.

Also, it's always a good idea to [search the issues](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues) for the project to see if anyone else has had this happen.

For some reason, the Cypress automation gets into a state where it thinks that you have no spec file. All Cypress does to [determine this is to see if there is a `location.hash` defined on the main window](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/develop/packages/runner/src/lib/window-util.js#L2) -> where it usually says `https://localhost:2020/__/#tests/integration/my_spec.js`.

Likely this is due to security mechanisms in the app that prevent your application from being run within an iframe (which is how Cypress runs all applications under test). Maybe in your application code it is something like:

```
if (top !== self) {
  top.location.href = self.location.href;
}
```

You can simply disable these checks while testing or in Cypress you can add to your test file (or a support file to have it work on every test file):

```
Cypress.on('window:before:load', (win) => {
  Object.defineProperty(win, 'self', {
    get: () => {
      return window.top
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: That `Cypress.on` block worked for me! As the GitHub link is now 404, could you please explain a bit more on how this works? Specifically how does the `Cypress.on` block trick Cypress into thinking there is a spec file even though it doesn't contain the `__/#tests/integration/my_spec.js` part of the path?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Usually this is related to the page moving out of the parent and can be solved by invoking the attribute and changing it to the current page.

```
cy.get('.approved-content .no-auto-submit').invoke('attr', 'target', '_self');
```